# 'DataTable' has no key defined

Tags: asp.net, datatable

The error occurs when I attempt to add the new migration.

I've googled around and it seems the go-to solution is to add a [Key] to the ID, but that does not work in my case. I suspect the error is conceptual. This is my model:

```
namespace steer.Models
{
    public class UpFile
    {
        [Display(Name="Auðkenni")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Nafn")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Hlaðið þann")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Tegund")]
        public string FileType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Stærð (kB)")]
        public int Size { get; set; }

        public DataTable Excel { get; set; }

        public class UpFileDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<UpFile> UpFiles { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

I just want to add a simple `DataTable` property to my model. Is that possible?

Edit: Full error message.

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

steer.Models.DataTable: : EntityType 'DataTable' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
steer.Models.CultureInfo: : EntityType 'CultureInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
steer.Models.DateTimeFormatInfo: : EntityType 'DateTimeFormatInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
DataTables: EntityType: EntitySet 'DataTables' is based on type 'DataTable' that has no keys defined.
CultureInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'CultureInfoes' is based on type 'CultureInfo' that has no keys defined.
DateTimeFormatInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'DateTimeFormatInfoes' is based on type 'DateTimeFormatInfo' that has no keys defined.
```